# Number of configurations of lines in $d$ dimensional space where any pair of them have the same angle.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solid-geometry

Let's define by $\eta(d,n)$ the number of distinct configurations of $n$ lines in $d$ dimensional space in a way that they all pass through the origin and the angle between any pair of lines is the same as any other pair. Here, distinct means that we shouldn't be able to take one configuration and superpose it on another with a simple rotation.

For example, $\eta(3,4) \geq 2$ because you can take the body diagonals of a cube or those of an Icosahedron and remove two.

Of course, we can always take two lines and place them at any angle to each other, so the configurations must have at least $3$ lines.

Is there a way to calculate this in closed-form or otherwise estimate it for arbitrary $d$ and $n$.

An obvious extension is the series $\gamma(d) = \sum\limits_{n=d+1}^\infty \eta(d,n)$, which defines the total number of non-trivial distinct configurations in $d$ dimensional space.

---

EDIT: It was pointed out in the comments that $\eta(d,n) = \infty$ for $1<n\leq d$. So the question is interesting when $n>d$.

---

Related: [How to draw six lines in 3-d space such that angle between any pair of them is the same.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217177/how-to-draw-six-lines-in-3-d-space-such-that-angle-between-any-pair-of-them-is-t)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what _distinct_ means here.

Comment: It means that if you're able to rotate one configuration and superpose it on another, you really only had one configuration.

Comment: Then it seems that $\eta(3, 3)$ is infinity. Three lines in $3d$ can be placed at any angle.

Comment: Yes indeed $\eta(n,d)$ is certainly infinite whenever $1<d\leq n$.

Comment: For $n=3$ consider a triangular pyramid of height $h>0$ with its top at the origin. Each value of $h$ gives a different angle between the three legs, so $\eta(3,3)=\infty$. Of course we can take a subset of the three legs to see that also $\eta(3,d)=\infty$ if $1<d\leq n$. And the same construction works for any $n$.

Comment: You're right. I guess the question is solved for the case $d \leq n$.

Comment: The sequence in the linked question ([link to OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002853)) gives an upper bound for $d$ in terms of $n$ for which $\eta(n,d)>0$. An interesting (?) question is a lower bound for $d$ in terms of $n$ for which $\eta(n,d)$ is finite. And another interesting follow-up question would be the sum over all $d$ for which $\eta(n,d)$ is finite (for fixed $n$).

Comment: Note that the numbers in the sequence correspond to configurations of lines that do not necessarily pass through the origin.

Comment: Perhaps you will get an idea if you take a look at proof of maximality https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203876/understanding-matouseks-proof-of-equiangular-lines/4203932#4203932

Comment: @Servaes - you meant the same construction works for any $d$ or any $n$?

Comment: For any $n$ you can take a pyramid with a regular $n$-gon as its base to see that $\eta(n,n)=\infty$, and by taking subsets of its legs, that $\eta(n,d)=\infty$ if $1<d\leq n$.

Comment: @Servaes - I'm calling in my question $d$ the number of dimensions and $n$ the number of lines. So for the case of $d=3$ and $n=6$, you get $d \leq n$, but $\eta(3,6)=1$, I think (the main diagonals of an Icosahedron).

Comment: @RohitPandey Ah, I swapped $n$ and $d$. Sorry for the confusion, I should have read more carefully.

Comment: No worries. Also, note that the AEIS link does indeed describe the sequence of lines that are equi-angular and pass through the origin. If you remove the passing through origin requirement, you always get $d(d+1)/2$ lines by taking the edges of the Tetrahedron-counterpart in that space.