# Number of distinct configurations of equiangular lines passing through origin

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

We have a $d$ dimensional space and want to place $n$ lines passing through the origin in such a way that the angles between any two pairs of lines is the same. Such a placement results in a configuration. Two configurations are considered identical if:

1. We can rotate one and get another.
2. We can start with one configuration, move the origin and get another.
3. Start with one and a combination of the above two leads to the other.

The first one is simple enough. For an example of the second one, consider the case of $d=3$. Now, consider three lines on the $x$-$y$ plane at $120$ degree angles. If we move the origin along the z-axis, we get a pyramid and the equiangular property is maintained. However, all these configurations are considered equivalent to the planar configuration (note the cartesian coordinate system is one of these pyramids). Another way to think of this is a tri-pod stand with origin at the head. You move the head up or down by gradually increasing or decreasing the angle between the legs of the tripod.

As an example of distinct configurations, consider again $d=3$ and $n=4$. We can either take the center of mass of a Tetrahedron (which is at the origin) and draw lines to each of the vertices. The angles between any two of these lines will be $60$ degrees. Or, we could take an Icosahedron and draw any $4$ of the main diagonals. The angle between any two of these is  about $97$ degrees. Also, we can't take the first configuration and move the origin to get the second one. Hence, these are at-least two distinct configurations for the case of $d=3$ and $n=4$.

Let's call the number of such configurations $\alpha(d,n)$. We therefore have: $\alpha(3,4)\geq 2$.

Is there a closed form or anything else we can say about $\alpha(d,n)$ in general?

---

NOTE:

I asked a very similar question earlier today: [Number of configurations of lines in $d$ dimensional space where any pair of them have the same angle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217709/number-of-configurations-of-lines-in-d-dimensional-space-where-any-pair-of-the). On asking, I realized via comments an added condition that would make it more interesting (condition #2 above). However, since the original question is still technically valid, I decided to leave it as-is.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the origin"? From your definition, all lines pass through $(0,0)$ by assumption; it's not clear to me what process you're describing.

Comment: Consider starting with the coordinate system in 3-d. Think of it as a model stick figure. Lay it on a table such that the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes are 1 unit in length, their ends rest on the table forming an equilateral triangle and the origin is above the table. Now push the origin down gently, maintaining the equiangular property. Once the origin touches the table, the angles between the three lines will be 120 degrees each. Does this clarify?

Comment: I agree this sort of thing works in the $(3,3)$ case, but it’s not clear to me what it would mean to move the origin relative to e.g. the four-like tetrahedral example you gave.

Comment: For any configuration, if you can move the origin with the lines staying attached to it (like in the example) and are able to get to another configuration, those two configurations are identical. In the Tetrahedron example with four lines, it would be impossible to move the origin and still maintain the equiangular property, leave alone hoping to get another valid configuration with this strategy.

Comment: BTW, the (3,3) case can also be thought of as a tripod with origin at the head and the only way to move the head up or down is by changing the angle between the legs.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that you're trying to count the (path-)connected components of the subspace of lines with equal angles in the space of unordered line orientations (with the usual topology, where we view the lines as points in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$)? That is, if there exists a continuous movement from one configuration to the other while maintaining equal angles at all times, we deem them equivalent?

Comment: I don't understand some of the terminology, but it does sound like that's what we want. If there is a continuous movement between two configurations, they're the same. Is this a concrete concept in Topology?

Comment: The claim "Doing it with a Tetrahedron produces four lines where any pair is at $60^{\circ}$" is not true. The angle is something like $70.5288^{\circ}$ or more accurately 
$\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$